# Connected app digital certificate automation

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps, identity-verification

I'm writing a wrapper over a salesforce instance and retrieving access token with the salesforce using JWT token. In this process, I've to manually upload the digital certificate in the connected app console.

Is there anyway to automate this process? I couldn't find any API for modifying the connected app meta. Or the only way is to increase the certificate validity

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to upload the certificate using the Metdata API and setting the `certificate` attribute under `ConnectedAppOauthConfig`. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm